# How can I troubleshoot Microsoft Intune sync failures due to "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" in "IntuneManagementExtension.log"?

Tags: windows, ssl

While investigating a machine that began failing to sync with Microsoft Intune after working fine for several weeks after its initial deployment, I noticed the following type of error throughout the `IntuneManagementExtension.log`, with the key finding being `Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel`:

```
<![LOG[[Discovery Service] Got gateway addr: https://r.manage.microsoft.com/devicegatewayproxy/cimhandler.ashx]LOG]!><time="10:28:15.8830749" date="12-4-2023" component="IntuneManagementExtension" context="" type="1" thread="54" file="">
<![LOG[[Location Service] Calling LocationService ServiceAddresses Controller with https://manage.microsoft.com/RestUserAuthLocationService/RestUserAuthLocationService/Certificate/ServiceAddresses with True]LOG]!><time="10:28:15.8987334" date="12-4-2023" component="IntuneManagementExtension" context="" type="1" thread="54" file="">
<![LOG[[Location Service] SendWebRequest, client-request-id: 55408d36-1360-4f26-9efe-a10289f95db5, Method: GET]LOG]!><time="10:28:15.8987334" date="12-4-2023" component="IntuneManagementExtension" context="" type="1" thread="54" file="">
<![LOG[[Location Service] Failed to Get Endpoint From LocationServiceServiceAddressesController with url https://manage.microsoft.com/RestUserAuthLocationService/RestUserAuthLocationService/Certificate/ServiceAddresses, thumbprint 887993A3C317BDBBCF20E0A560D111DF3D9788B5,True, WebException status SecureChannelFailure message The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. full System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.Management.Services.IntuneWindowsAgent.AgentCommon.DiscoveryService.GetEndpointFromLocationServiceServiceAddressesController(X509Certificate2 deviceCertificate, Guid deviceId)]LOG]!><
```

How can I troubleshoot this TLS failure further? I'm not clear as to whether the actual URL to which the connection is failing is `https://manage.microsoft.com/RestUserAuthLocationService/RestUserAuthLocationService/Certificate/ServiceAddresses`, and if so, if the attempt to secure the connection with TLS is using the certificate with thumbprint `887993A3C317BDBBCF20E0A560D111DF3D9788B5`.

Indeed, the certificate with that thumbprint is installed in the `Computer Certificates -> Personal` certificate store, and is issued by `Microsoft Intune Root Certification Authority`. The certificate status when viewed in the Certificate Management console is `This certificate is OK.`

Is there some way that I can reproduce this failure with `openssl`, `curl`, etc., or otherwise continue troubleshooting it?

**Workstation vitals:**

```
Edition Windows 11 Enterprise
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎6/‎2/‎2023
OS build    22621.2715
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22677.1000.0
```

**Trust configuration:**

There isn't anything unusual about this workstation's trust or PKI configuration. It uses the stock/default Windows `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`, and the only related GPOs add a couple of internal certificates (such as those for our domain controllers or trusted code-signers) to the trust store; there are no policies of which I'm aware that restrict or revoke trust. The computer is not behind a proxy.